# Append removing element content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dynamic navigation which adds elements to a standard bootstrap navigation with the following code:

```
// Map item to the navigation
function addToNavigation (navigationItem) {

  // Build the navigation item HTML string
  var navigationItemHTML = '<li><a';
  if(navigationItem.dataTarget){ navigationItemHTML += ' data-target="#' + navigationItem.dataTarget + '" data-toggle="collapse"';}
  navigationItemHTML += ' aria-expanded="false" class="pointer">';
  if(navigationItem.icon){ navigationItemHTML += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-' + navigationItem.icon + '></span> ';}
  navigationItemHTML += navigationItem.title + '</a></li>';

  // Append the new item to the navigation
  $('#navigation').append(navigationItemHTML);
}
```

If I set a breakpoint the contents of "navigationItemHTML" appear exactly how I want them however the result on the page omits the navigation item title and the optional glyphicon.

Why is this and is there a better way of accomplishing what I want to achieve in jQuery/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure out it was a problem with the string I was trying to pass to jQuery, I had more luck instantiating each tag as an element within the last:

```
// Map item to the navigation
function addToNavigation (navigationItem) {

  // Build the navigation item HTML string
  var navigationItemHTML = $('<li></li>').html(
                              $('<a></a>').html(
                                $('<span></span>').html(
                                  ' ' + navigationItem.title).prepend(
                                    $('<span><span>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-' + navigationItem.icon)))
                                      .attr('data-target', '#' + navigationItem.dataTarget)
                                        .attr('data-toggle', 'collapse').addClass('pointer'));

  // Append the new item to the navigation
  $('#navigation').append(navigationItemHTML);
}
```

I still think this looks abit messy however, please let me know if anyone finds a more elegant solution.